# Kendo DateTimePicker Culture Doesn't work Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo data picker to display the date, I want to have the date information in French for that I used the efficient script in my layout page like bellow:

```
<script>
        kendo.Culture("fr-FR");
    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/culture/kendo.fr-FR.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.tooltip.min.js"></script>
</script>
```

I even add the globalize script but even that the culture doesn’t change:

```
![<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.fr-FR.js"></script>][1]
```

[image]
This my kendo datapicker image:

@chxzy here is my kendo datapicker

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m./****).Events(e => e.Open("onOpen")).Footer("Today - #=kendo.toString(data, 'd') #").MonthTemplate("# if ($.inArray(+data.date, birthdays) != -1) { #" +
                                     "<div class=\"birthday\"></div>" +
                                 "# } #" +
                                 "#= data.value #")
                   .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
                           .Culture("fr-FR")
    )
```

and here is my script code:

```
var today = new Date(),
    birthdays = [
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 11),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 6),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 27),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 3),
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 22)
    ];

function onOpen() {
    var dateViewCalendar = this.dateView.calendar;
    if (dateViewCalendar) {
        dateViewCalendar.element.width(340);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try adding the following to your datepicker js code.

```
$("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
  culture: "fr-FR",
  //....
})
```

**EDIT**

After reviewing your Kendo MVC code, can you try changing the folowing as I think manually specifying the format for the footer will fix this.

This:

```
.Footer("Today - #=kendo.toString(data, 'd') #")
```

to this:

```
.Footer("Today - #=kendo.toString(data, 'dd/MM/yyyy') #")
```

Comment: my kendo datapicker have a dynamic id i can't fix his id ti put it in  $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({ !! what should i do?

Comment: Well you can pass the id to the script and then have '$(myId).kendoDatePicker();' - if you can post your js code it would be helpful.

Comment: my id when i search with firebug is like this: objects_7989f7d0-b85c-4963-9787-87e8b30a1b78__Criteria_1__Search and it is dynamic so i can't fix the id, i haven't any script just the script of kendo datapicker like in the demo : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/template

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `kendo.Culture("fr-FR");` before you included your corresponding culture JavaScript file.

If so, include your js file first and then call kendo.Culture...

```
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/culture/kendo.fr-FR.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script>
    kendo.Culture("fr-FR");
</script>
```